# How Can I Get the value from the below format in swift Language?

Tags: ios, swift, nsobject

Response:

```
{
    "access_token" = 91BB0E206CC453B75349F185876F0D80;
    nickname = Hari;
    "open_id" = 4889ACDAA79490B10E4F196876144181;
    province = "";
}
```

I need to get the access_token,nickname from the above response.

**MyCode in Swiftenter code here**

```
    let jsonObjects=object as! NSArray
    for dataDict : Any in jsonObjects 
    {
     let access_token: NSString! = (dataDict as AnyObject).object(forKey:  "access_token") as! NSString
     let nickname: NSString! = (dataDict as AnyObject).object(forKey:  "nickname") as! NSString
     print (access_token!)
     print (nickname!)
    }
```

**Error:**

```
Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryM' (0x114a120e0) to 'NSArray' (0x114a11c58).
```

Comment: (As your error states that) cast `object` to `NSDictionary` as follows:- `let jsonObjects=object as! NSDictionary`

Comment: exactly, `let jsonObjects=object as! NSDictionary` and do not use the `for` loop...

Comment: Ohh.Nice working fine thank you..!!

Comment: Even better would be to use `guard let jsonObjects=object as? Dictionary<String, Any> else { return }`

Comment: This ia not a json response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to avoid such crashes, a better way to access json data is the following:

```
if let json = jsonData as? [String: Any] {
    if let token = json["access_token"] as? String {
        self.accesToken = token
    }
    if let nickname = json["nickname"] as? String {
        self.nickname = nickname
    }
}
```

You can cast each of the objects to the type you expect them to be, if they are not, nothing happens. If you need something to happen, you can and an `else` to each of the checks.